# Approximation of a harmonic function on the unit disc by harmonic polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ be a real valued harmonic function on the open unit disc $D_1(0) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Show that there exists a sequence of real valued harmonic polynomials that converges uniformly on compact subsets of $D_1(0)$ to $u$.

Now, consider the harmonic function $u = \ln|z|$ on the open set $\Omega = \{ z : 1<|z| < 2\}$. Is it possible to find a sequence of harmonic polynomials which converge uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$ to $u$?

I am preparing for my qualifying exam in complex analysis and this question has come up. I will admit that I have not made much progress, but I do have a few thoughts, which I give below. My hope is to receive a few nice hints, and then I will post a solution of my own.

From my complex analysis course, I know that the convexity of $D_1(0)$ allows us to define a harmonic conjugate $v$ for $u$ on $D_1(0)$. Then $f \equiv u + iv$ is analytic on $D_1(0)$. Then maybe I can use a theorem from complex analysis to produce this sequence of harmonic polynomials?

For the second question, I am assuming that the answer is no, likely due to the fact that we cannot define a harmonic conjugate for $ u = \ln|z|$ on the set $\Omega$ under investigation.

Hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, following your thoughts, let $f$ be holomorphic(i.e. analytic) on $D_1(0)$, such that ${\rm Re}f=u$, i.e. $u$ is the real part of $f$. Then the Taylor expansion of $f$
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$$ 
converges to $f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $D_1(0)$(and hence so do the corresponding real and imaginary parts). For every $n\ge 0$, let 
$$u_n(z)={\rm Re}\big(\sum_{k=0}^n a_kz^k \big).$$
Since $u_n$ is the real part of a (holomorphic) polynomial of $z=x+iy$, $u_n$ is a real valued harmonic polynomial of $x$ and $y$. Moreover, $u_n$ converges to the real part of $f$, which is just $u$, uniformly on compact subsets of $D_1(0)$.

---

For the second question, assume that there is a sequence of real valued harmonic polynomials $(u_n)$, such that it converges to $\ln|z|$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$. Note that $u_n$ is in fact harmonic on $D_2(0)$, so by maximum/minimum principle, it is easy to see that $u_n$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $D_2(0)$, and let us denote the limit by $u$. Then using Poisson integral formula or otherwise, it is easy to see that $u$ is harmonic on $D_2(0)$. However, since $\ln|z|$ is not harmonic at $0$, it contradicts to the fact that $u=\ln|z|$ on $\Omega$, so such $(u_n)$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Landscape! I understand your answer to the first question just fine. But I am still struggling to grasp some of the things you say in your second answer. If the polynomials are harmonic on $\Omega$, how do we know that they are harmonic on $D_2(0)$? I'm sure there's an easy answer to this that I'm just not being mindful of. Also, can you show me more explicitly how we use the Poisson formula to get that the $u_n$ converge uniformly on compact subsets of $D_2(0)$? Or just hints for both of these questions are fine. Thanks again!

Comment: @jtms88: You are welcome. In below $G$ denotes some nonempty open set of $\Bbb R^2$. 1) If $P(x,y)$ is a harmonic polynomial of $x$, $y$ on $G$, then $\Delta P=0$ on $G$. Note that $\Delta P$ is still a polynomial, so you only need to show that if a polynomial of $x$, $y$ vanishes on $G$, then it must be the zero polynomial.  2) It is a well known result that  uniformly convergent limit of harmonic functions is still harmonic. Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of harmonic functions on $G$ converges to $u$ uniformly on compact sets.

Comment: @jtms88: To show $u$ is harmonic, it suffices to show when $\overline{D_r(z)}\subset G$, $u$ is harmonic on $D_r(z)$. Since $u_n$ is harmonic, on $D_r(z)$ it equals to its Poisson integral over $\partial D_r(z)$. Since $u_n$ converges to $u$ uniformly on   $\overline{D_r(z)}$, it follows that on $D_r(z)$ $u$ also equals to its Poisson integral over $\partial D_r(z)$, which implies that $u$ is harmonic on $D_r(z)$.

Comment: @jtms88: Sorry, I misread your second question. Poisson integral was to show $u$ is harmonic, and it is irrelevant to the statement of your second question. If $u_n$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$, then in particular it converges uniformly on the circle $\{|z|=r\}$ for any $1<r<2$. Note that $u_n-u_m$ is harmonic, both of whose maximum and minimum on $\{|z|\le r\}$ are attained on $\{|z|=r\}$. It follows that $u_n-u_m$ is a uniform Cauchy sequence on $\{|z|\le r\}$, i.e. $u_n$ converges uniformly on $\{|z|\le r\}$.